# Unable to write and update binary file properly

Tags: c++, binary

I am able to choose which record to update, whats the student id to be changed into as well as the name. However it would not record into the binary file in the end as when i choose to view my binary file - all the records stay the same in the end. Do enlighten!

Best, MM

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 100;

struct student
{
    int identity;
    char name[MAX];
    int notask;
    int atask[MAX];
    int finalmark; 
};


void updateRecord (fstream& bfilem1, const char bfilenamem1[])
{
    char updateRecord;
    int k;
    student s;

    bfilem1.open(bfilenamem1, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    if (!bfilem1)
    {
        cout << "Updating of binary " << bfilenamem1 
             << " has failed" << endl;
        bfilem1.close();
    }

    int i=1;

    cout << "Begin updating of binary file " << bfilenamem1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Information for student file" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    while (bfilem1.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&s), sizeof (s)))
    {
        cout << i << "\t"
             << s.identity << " "
             << s.name << endl;
        i++;
    }

    bfilem1.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    do 
    {   
        cout << "Update record: ";
        cin >> k;
        cout << endl;

        // Take out record
        bfilem1.seekg ((k - 1) * sizeof (student), ios::beg);
        bfilem1.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&s), sizeof (s));        

        // Update record
        cout << "Student ID: ";
        cin >> s.identity;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Update the name: ";
        cin.getline(s.name, MAX);

        // Put back record
        bfilem1.seekp ((k - 1) * sizeof (student), ios::beg);
        bfilem1.write (reinterpret_cast <const char *>(&s), sizeof (s));

        cout << "Student ID " << s.identity << " updated" << endl;
        cout << "Any more update (y/n): ";
        cin >> updateRecord;
        cout << endl;

    } while ((updateRecord=='y')||(updateRecord=='Y'));

    // Close bfile
    bfilem1.close();
}
```

Comment: Show the definition of `student` please.

Comment: What is `student`?  If it is a non-POD type, none of this code will work.

Comment: @RichardCritten Done!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie student is a struct!

Comment: @KayzelMoo Being a `struct` has nothing to do with whether the type is POD or not.  `struct s { std::string name; };` is non-POD.  However what you posted is a POD type.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie any advice?

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to singly execute statements and *watch* values of variables.

Comment: What happens when `k <= 0` in your `do-while` loop?  Also, you should check the record number against the number of records in the file (don't accept record indices that are too big).

Comment: Check the status of `bfilem1` after every use of the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes when we work with binary or text files the use of pointer can give us a bad play, try to close your file and open it again before using anoter pointer (seekg or seekp). Also check the case when k<=0||k>=i before search the records in the file

```
// Update record
    cout << "Student ID: ";
    cin >> s.identity;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Update the name: ";
    cin.getline(s.name, MAX);
    bfilem1.close();
    bfilem1.open(bfilenamem1, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    // Put back record
    bfilem1.seekp((k - 1) * sizeof(student), ios::beg);
    bfilem1.write(reinterpret_cast <const char *>(&s), sizeof(s));
```